# How to splice a string at second position and add it to an array?

Tags: arrays, arduino, array-splice

In the following code, displayChar() gets the value as a,b,c,d,e,f.
But I want it as ab,cd,ef.
How can I do that?

```
void displayString(char* s)
{
  for (int i = 0; i<=strlen(s); i++)
  {
  displayChar(s[i]);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  displayString("abcdef");
}

void displayChar(char c)
{
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not part of the answer: your loop should only go until i < strlen(s) otherwise you will get an out of bounds crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void displayString(char* s)
{
  for (int i = 0; i<=strlen(s); i+=2)
  {
      char temp[3] = {s[i], s[i+1],'\0'};
      displayChar( temp );
  }
}

void loop()
{
  displayString("abcdef");
}

void displayChar(char* c)
{
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but its give me the following error:"invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'"

Comment: Odd, I copied it into a sketch (but moved the displayChar(char* c) function to the top). It worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Instead if using i++ in your for loop you can increase i not by one but by two, that way i will be 0, 2, 4, etc. Then your two chars are s[i] and s[i+1]. Pass these to a new function that takes two chars (or an array of chars) as arguments and prints them.

Comment: Thanks for your help Genuigr. I changed i++ to i+2, but its only printing letter a.

Comment: If you only call displayChar(s[i]); that is what happens. You can call displayChar(s[i+1]); also or you create a new function that accepts two chars that you want to display

Comment: I tried displayChar(s[i+1]), but its printing only b now.

Comment: Can you show me how to create a function that takes two chars?

Comment: void displayChars(char a, char b) {}

Comment: Thanks again.But it was printing only a & b. So I changed displayChar(s[i+1]) to displayChar(s[i++]) and it started printing a,a,b,b,c,c etc. Also I want the output as ab, but its printing as a,b.

Comment: Instead of i++ in the loop increment, make it i+= 2.  Do not increment i in the DisplayChars call